Mac Photos Restoring from iCloud
I have 30,000 photos and 3,000 videos in Photos.  I've only decided to store these on iCloud now and have paid for 2TB space but Photos on the Mac seems to be stuck on Restoring from iCloud
I have synced recent photos and video from my iPhone and they show up on iCloud.com but not on the Mac. (5,000 files)

How long have you left it? What exactly is it showing?

Thanks, I was waiting 2 days and although we don't have a great wifi connection, it works to update software and Mac OS updates etc! Eventually brought equipment to a Wifi hub and the files are now showing up on iCloud.com transferring at about 400 files per hour so now up to 17,000 transferred.

Life would be so much easier if Apple did a better job with messaging in Photos. Instead of:
29,981 Photos, 2,970 Videos
Restoring from iCloud
The number should change according to what's left.
Conclusion:  Answer seems to be patience and good WiFi of you are fortunate to have it.
